# Deliver JMS message to a single node in a Weblogic Cluster with a Distributed Topic

Tags: jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

I would like to have my Weblogic cluster listen on a distributed topic.  Whenever a JMS message is sent on that topic, I would like for only one node in the cluster to handle this message.  Is this possible?

I can't use a distributed queue because there are multiple listeners (other clusters) on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WebLogic 10.3.4 this is possible with Partitioned TOpics.  In order to enable this you should set the replication mode to 'Partitioned'.  The default is 'Replicated' which delivers the message to every node in the cluster.